# RVIZ Transform error

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-melodic

I am working on a custom spherical robot with two motors which controls the two pendulum and one motor which drives the robot.

When RViz is launched: The Global option > Fixed frame is set to base_link and shows all the transforms except the following mentioned links.

An error appears for the pendulum link and hull link with message saying:

```
No transform from [pend2_link] to [base_link]
```

**Please tell me why some transformations are showing properly and some are not.**

What I have tried: I have the `.urdf` file of the robot, so I tried changing the joint origin values in URDF.

[image: Screenshot of Displays]

Comment: Can you link to or embed the urdf?  What does `rosrun tf2_tools echo.py base_link pend2_link` tell you?  You should also look at rqt node graph